# Why ActiveRecord::Calculations.maximum return TIme object instead of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, activesupport

I had a code like this:

```
Foo.order(:posted_at).last.posted_at
```

And I learned better way to write it.

```
Foo.maximum(:posted_at)
```

But I noticed `maximum` returns `Time` object while another way returns `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, and as far as I know Rails basically returns `TimeWithZone`. Why `maximum` returns normal `Time` object?

```
Foo.maximum(:posted_at).class
# Time < Object
Foo.order(:posted_at).last.posted_at.class
# ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone < Object
```

Comment: It's `activerecord` issue: model instantiating and calculations(max, sum etc) go different way. Model instance does cast to `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` while calculation code does not intersect with model code and does not do cast

Comment: I got it, thanks! If you post the comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `Activerecord` issue. Casting to `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` is implemented on `model` level. Try in console:

```
model_instance = MyModel.new
t = Time.now # not Time.current
model_instance.created_at.class
t.class # Time
model_instance.created_at = t
model_instance.created_at.class # ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

The `maximum` (`count`, `sum` etc) [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c4c8d808d0054dff9bf6e783638b8ea2f3499da1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb) does not intersects with `model` one and does not do such casting.